# Test hooks weights using dbWeights

Tags: weight, testing

Imagine I have a `on_initialize` hook like this:

```rust
    impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
        fn on_initialize(n: T::BlockNumber) -> Weight {
            return T::DbWeight::get().writes(1);
        }
    }
```

I'd like a test that can verify the hook, something like this:

```rs
    #[test]
    fn valid_weights() {
        new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
            assert_eq!(
                <MyPallet as OnInitialize<u64>>::on_initialize(1),
                <TestRuntime as sp_weights>::DbWeight::get().writes(2) //<-- sp_weight is unknown
            );
        })
    }
}
```

/!\ I use substrate branch `polkadot-v0.9.22`, where sp_weight is not available as a package, so I can't import it

the problem is... That I can't find a way to do it. I couldn't find a way to use something like `Test::DbWeight::get().writes(1)`, the closest I could get was this:

```rs
    <<TestRuntime as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight>::get().reads(1)
```

but I get this error:

```
   type annotations needed
   cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the trait `Get`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, but the `sp_weights` is not needed.
I think in your case the Rust compiler is just being annoying.
You can write it more explicit like this  to help the type-interference understand what you want:

```rust
#[test]
fn valid_weights() {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_support::weights::RuntimeDbWeight;

    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        let db_weights: RuntimeDbWeight = <TestRuntime as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight::get();

        assert_eq!(
            MyPallet::on_initialize(1),
            db_weights.writes(2)
        );
    })
}
```

Comment: I was so close omg, i was just searching in the wrong direction ! Thanks a lot for helping me out !